# unequal columns in two different select clause used union clause

Tags: mysql, union

unequal columns in two different select clause used union clause.

In mysql, we should have same number of columns defined in select clauses in 2 queries with UNION clause.

so, to acheive the above, i am doing its like this:

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4
FROM table1
{whereclause}
UNION
SELECT c1, c2, NULL, NULL
FROM table2
{whereclause}
```

but in my application at some places the no. of columns in first select clause is unkown to me, so couldn't hardcode `'NULL'`.

one thing is constant i.e. in second `SELECT clause c1, c2` will remain same troughout, but i want to append `'NULL'` in select clause to match the equal number of columns in select clause 1.

how can i acheive the above.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully, I have understood you.

If you wish to extract data from two tables, they dont need to have identical numbers of columns, but they DO need to have something in common.

The generic sytnax would be:

```
SELECT table1.col1, table2.col1 FROM table1 LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.col3=table2.col3 WHERE {where conditions}
```

What is important here is that there is a linking bit of data - often a usernumber that is common to both tables and means the same thing in both tables.

Answer (score 0):

Try to assign `ALIAS` to your NULL column's name

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4
FROM table1
{whereclause}
UNION
SELECT c1, c2, NULL as c3, NULL as c4
FROM table2
{whereclause}
```

Remember that data types need to match for the same column in each select.